# SQL Server error: the paging file is too small for this operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2008

I'm running SQL Server 2012 Express (v 11.0.3000) on a virtual server running Windows Server 2008 R2.  Over the past couple of weeks, the SQL Server has been randomly crashing or hanging.  Looking at the SQL server log, it seems that right before the crashes I'm getting an error saying "Could not load the DLL dbghelp.dll or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 1455(The paging file is too small for this operation..."

I'm confused as to whether this is referencing the SQL Server paging file or the Windows paging file.  Because this is a virtual server, Virtual Memory is disabled in Windows system configuration. When I go to the task manager, it shows I have 94,089 MB of free physical memory.  I found an article stating that in a virtual server, all the memory is virtual anyway, so to the virtualized instance of Windows, it all looks like physical memory.  So if the server has this much memory available, I don't understand why SQL Server's paging file would be too small.

When I search for this 1455 error message, I found this article (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1487760-5-1.aspx) which suggests reducing the max server memory. I assume it means reducing the maximum server memory setting in the Server Properties in SQL Server.  Currently this is set to 1024 MB.  This seems counterintuitive to reduce the server memory in this situation. Plus, 1GB doesn't seem like a lot.

When I go to the General tab of SQL Server properties, the value for Memory is 4096 (MB).

Below is a screenshot of the SQL Server log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U187e.png)

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DLL error is just a consequence of a low memory condition. SQL Server is not able to allocate dinamically more memory to processes.
Maximum Server Memory is a parameter used to define the maximum amount of memory sql server can allocate.
You have to raise it: 1024MB is a very low value for a producton database.
See more details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067(v=sql.110).aspx

SQL Server **Express** is free but has limitations like maximum usable memory: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143685(v=sql.105).aspx
...and it's 1GB. I'm sorry but probably you have to upgrade to Standard. :(